# Unable to get a simple plugin admin page to work

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu, debug, ide

Even though I have years of software development experience, I am new to WP & PHP development, so please bear with me.

After reading through [the plugin manual](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/), I started with a [WP plugin boiler plate](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate.git), made all the required field and name changes, added a custom capability, and, as a first real functionality, tried to add a simple admin interface for the plugin like so:

```
<?php

class Plugin_Name_Admin {

    // some code ommitted, the actual code uses my plugin's name, slugs, and fields

    public function init() {
        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'add_plugin_admin_menu'));
    }

    function add_plugin_admin_menu() {
            add_menu_page(
                'Plugin Name',
                'Plugin Menu',
                PLUGIN_USER_CAPABILITY,
                'plugin-name-admin',
                array( $this, 'admin_page' ),
                null,
                1
            );
        }
    
    function admin_page() {
        if ( current_user_can( PLUGIN_USER_CAPABILITY ) ) {
            require_once plugin_dir( __FILE__ ) . 'partials/plugin-name-admin-display.php';
        }
    }
}
```

The menu shows up for the users that have the assigned capability and the URL looks like `http://wp.localhost/wp-admin/admin.php?page=plugin-name-admin` but neither an administrator nor another user with the `PLUGIN_USER_CAPABILITY` can access that page. The error message is "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." and the error occurs in `wp-admin/includes/plugin.php` in the function `user_can_access_admin_page` where WP checks the following:

```
        if ( ! isset( $_registered_pages[ $hookname ] ) ) {
            return false;
        }
```

The hookname it uses is `admin_page_plugin-name-admin-admin`.

What am I missing?

Also, any pointers on how to properly debug WP code in PhpStorm would be greatly appreciated. So far, I've just been muddling around with added error messages.

**EDIT:** The `Plugin_Name_Admin` class is instantiated in the boilerplate code's main class in the `define_admin_hooks` function, which also adds the hook for the `init` function:

```
    private function define_admin_hooks() {

        $plugin_admin = new Plugin_Name_Admin( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );

        $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_styles' );
        $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_scripts' );
        $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_init', $plugin_admin, 'init' );

    }
```

This function is called from the constructor of the main class and uses the boiler plate's loader approach to create hooks.

As I mention in my answer below, changing the call to `add_plugin_admin_menu` from a hook for `admin_menu` to a direct call solved the permission error.

**EDIT2:** I got PhpStorm to work with [XDebug](https://xdebug.org) using [this write-up](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.3/zero-configuration-debugging.html).

Comment: can you enable the logs and get a full error? might give you a better idea.

Comment: Where and when is `Plugin_Name_Admin` created? Your question only shows the definition of the class, not how it's used/created/instantiated, _when_ you do it matters, so does where. Also what is the value of `PLUGIN_USER_CAPABILITY` and where does it come from?  Have you eliminated this as a possibility by using a known capability that comes in standard WordPress installs rather than a custom capability? e.g. `manage_options` which administrators have would provide a test case for that theory

Comment: I had the WP_DEBUG log enabled but it remained empty. The WP code doesn't seem to contain any debug or error generating lines either.

As for where `Plugin_Name_Admin` is created, I had assumed some familiarity with the boilerplate code but I'll edit the question to make it clearer. `PLUGIN_USER_CAPABILITY` is, as stated, a custom capability used as a string constant. `manage_options` would not give me a menu for either the administrator nor any other user.

Comment: Just looked at the source code of WP Plugin Boilerplate and I don't like it at all (my personal opinion). It uses a lot of things I consider bad practice and would block if anyone of my colleagues tried to do. E.g. "class-X.php" filenames manually required, instead of using PSR-4 autoloading. Also the way classes are used makes it a testing nightmare as well as abstracts some important parts heavily away. I can't find a better boilerplate right now, but being a fan of Roots.io work I recommend checking [Soil](https://github.com/roots/soil) source code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as it usually goes, after banging my head on this for hours yesterday and then finally deciding to ask for help, I was able to solve it within a few minutes. Here is what I needed to change:

```
    public function init() {
        // add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'add_plugin_admin_menu'));
        $this-> add_plugin_admin_menu();
    }
```

Clearly, I have much to learn about the call chain in WP.

Comment: I guess that means admin_menu is called before admin_init. You could probably also just `add_action('admin_menu',` in the class constructor.